# rj package not available for R version 3.1.2

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

Hello I am tring to install R in eclipse. At first I was getting the following error message

```
"Launching the R Console was cancelled, because it seems starting the 
R engine failed. Please make sure that R package 'rj' (2.0 or compatible)
is installed and that the R library paths are set correctly for the R 
environment configuration 'R firstRTest'."
```

I found someone with the same error: [StatET in Eclipse and R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502667/statet-in-eclipse-and-r)

However when I went proceeded with the suggested solution I ran:

```
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.0")
```

in an R console, I got the following error message:

```
packages ‘rj’, ‘rj.gd’ are not available (for R version 3.1.2)
```

Any help is appreciated. I am new to this so please keep it simple (as simple as possible) for me.

Comment: Try adding `type="source"` as a parameter (though the compilation of one of the pkgs failed on my Mavericks system)

Comment: Sorry, could you explain how I would do that?

Comment: `install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.0", type="source") `

Comment: It seems to have worked but I got the following message.
http://i.imgur.com/3Q2RMzb.png

Sorry for screen cap it was too long to comment. What do I do now? Sorry for asking things that are probably obvious.
thank you